# jQuery tabs - long tab names, small browser window - how to display on one line still?

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, resize

I've started looking at jQuery's built-in tabs functionality here:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs

Is there any way if you have long tab names, to format them nicely when resizing the browser window (ie. the window getting narrower)? At the moment, the tabs just flow to the next line. What I'd ideally like to see is all the tabs remaining on the one row, but getting narrower proportionally, and the text flowing to a 2nd (3rd, etc) line. Therefore expanding the tabs height. And if there is then a mix of number of lines in each tab, the tab heights all match.

I know it is good practice to keep tab names short, but I cannot in this instance. I'm only talking about 3-4 words per tab name. Nothing ridiculous!

So if anyone has a nice CSS trick (which works in most current browsers) I'd love to hear it please! Or if there is another existing jquery tab solution I could use, that would be great too :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a good solution is to [convert the menu to a dropdown](http://css-tricks.com/13303-convert-menu-to-dropdown/) for narrow screen resolutions

Comment: Thanks :) It's a really elegant solution, and one I'll definitely adopt! But it's not suitable for this application unfortunately.